# Right continuity property of the cumulative distribution function?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I have been studying probability from Sheldon Ross' A First Course in Probability. And the following property of cumulative distribution function was stated: CDFs are right continuous. And the following example was presented:

[image]

I am not totally sure, as to why when we do the probability of P(X $\le$ c) where c is some constant, we basically have that additionally $$\frac{1}{n}$$ term. Can someone help me understand it? I specifically want to know what is the physical interpretation behind having that term and why we need it to rigorously prove P(X $\le$ c).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you want to find the probability of $P(X<c)$ whereas $F(x)$ only gives you the probability of $P(X\leq c)$. Take part a) for example, we know that
$$\bigcup_n\left\{X\leq 3-\frac{1}{n}\right\} = \{X<3\}$$
and the sets on the LHS is nested such that
$$\left\{X\leq 3-\frac{1}{n}\right\}\subseteq \left\{X\leq 3-\frac{1}{n+1}\right\}$$
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, by continuity from below of the probability measure, we have
$$P(\{X<3\}) = P\left(\bigcup_n\left\{X\leq 3-\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right) = \lim_n P\left(\left\{X\leq 3-\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right).$$
Now, you have a good handle on the RHS of the above equation by simply using $F$.

Comment: How did you get the very first expression? What does that mean?

Comment: In probability, we have an underlying sample space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space, $\mathscr{F}$ is the set of events, and $P$ is the probability measure. Notations like $\{X\leq k\}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$ is often shorthand for $\{\omega\in \Omega:X(\omega)\leq k\}$ with the understanding that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is our random variable (i.e. a measurable map).